# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytest-config (unavailable) (from versions: 0.0.8, 0.0.9, 0.0.10, 0.0.11)

Tags: python-3.x

> pip install pytest-config

prompts the following error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytest-config (unavailable) (from versions: 0.0.8, 0.0.9, 0.0.10, 0.0.11)

Novice Seeking Guidance， thanks.

remarks:

> python version 3.9.5

> pytest version  6.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Also tried the following methods to get the same prompt：
pip install git+git://github.com/buzzfeed/pytest_config.git@#egg=pytest_config==